# Need help removing onscreen caps lock indicator (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, notifications, logitech-mouse

This indicator is driving me bonkers, it has shown up on both my home and work laptop and I have no idea why. The advice I've gotten from google suggests going to a Screen configurations tab in advanced display settings to turn off caps lock indicators but that tab does not appear on either computer. I am using a logitech MX Master 2S mouse and a Keychron K8 TKL keyboard which is attached to both laptops,

[image: annoying caps lock indicator]

Comment: You will have to be more specific (screenshot) than the "caps lock indicator" description you have provide since Windows doesn't typically have one.

Comment: I have that indicator (my laptops, not my desktop). Indicator goes away in 3 seconds.  Just be patient. Desktop Logitech has a green LED on the caps lock key and does not display on screen. Just adapt.

Comment: @John the issue is that I don't want the indicator to appear at all. Just adapt isn't an answer to the question.

Comment: @Ramhound sorry, my first post so I hadn't figured out adding images yet! Image added

Comment: That overlay is handled by third-party software

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In the event you have Logitech Options installed but can't find the settings screen other answers talk about:**

(copied from my response to a similar post)

From my experience this is most commonly caused by either Logitech's `SetPoint` software or `LogitechOptions` software (different software for different models of peripherals).

While I'm not sure about `SetPoint`, for `LogitechOptions` there is apparently a bug where the CAPSLOCK notification can get toggled and then stay on. This usually happens if you plug in a logitech keyboard as the software defaults to having that option on.

Normally you can go into the keyboard options and disable the pop-up, however if you no longer have the keyboard plugged in then the software just doesn't give you the menu to disable the option.

The easiest way I've found to quickly fix this is by modifying the settings file directly:

1. On `Windows`, navigate to your local app data - WIN+R  --> `%appdata%\Logishrd\LogiOptions`
2. Find **options.xml** and open in a text editor of some sorts
3. Find and modify the line `<useroption name="showLockNotifications" value="1" />` to have `value=0` to disable the notification
4. Restart / open `LogitechOptions` software to let changes take effect
5. Regain sanity

Answer (score 1):

Just went to **Logitech options app** -> **settings** -> **toggle caps lock notification option**

[image: Logitech options app settings page]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is caused by the logitech options app (comes with their mice and keyboards, in my case came with my logitech MX Master 2S mouse. It turns out there's some kind of bug in the logitech options app around this caps lock indicator, by default it isn's switched on but can randomly become switched on. There is an option to switch off the notification but it doesn't appear unless you have a logitech keyboard installed, which I didn't. My solution was to remove the logitech options app, which isn't perfect but was better than that horrible indicator.

Comment: even after uninstall its still there. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

@Ellis I ran into the same problem the other day (with an MX Master 3), though I didn't want to remove Options as I use a lot of custom button mapping.

Anyways, I figured out that if you download Logitech Setpoint (https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360025141274), it will give you that missing option to add/remove the notifications for caps/num lock keys being pressed. I turned this off, hit apply, and the notifications stopped.

I also did this on my girlfriend's computers as she uses the MX Vertical and was annoyed with the same issue. For hers, it didn't resolve the issue until I connected my mouse to her computer, though I don't know if that was an issue with her computer or something software-related.

Hopefully this helps with yours as well, so that you can keep using Options.

Update: So today, the notification came back. I had been receiving some update notification from Logitech all day and not paying attention, and just noticed that when I hit Caps Lock, it popped up on the screen as before. I uninstalled/reinstalled Setpoint and the notification was again gone. I'm not sure what the connection is, but I've disabled Setpoint's software updates to hopefully avoid the issue in the future.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to use the Logitech Options application, you can disable the Caps lock indicator by following below steps

1. Open Logitech Options
2. Click on the Keyboard
3. Click More -> This device
4. Under Notifications -> untick -> **A lock key is pressed**

This will remove the cap locks indicator.

Comment: This only works if you have a compatible logitech keyboard. If you are just using the app for just a mouse then the keyboard section is disabled leaving you unable to untick the option you are referring to

Comment: Yes that's correct, my solution will only work if compatible keyboard is connected.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Logitech Options, then you can go to settings and scroll down to where it says "Caps Lock, Num Lock, Scroll Lock and Fn Lock Notifications" and turn it off

Comment: That setting doesn't appear if you don't have a logitech keyboard connected to the PC. See this in the accepted answer:
_"....there is apparently a bug where the CAPSLOCK notification can get toggled and then stay on. This usually happens if you plug in a logitech keyboard as the software defaults to having that option on.

Normally you can go into the keyboard options and disable the pop-up, *however if you no longer have the keyboard plugged in then the software just doesn't give you the menu to disable the option.*"_

Answer (score 0):

For the record, there are 3 programs.

Setpoint: it works for older hardware.
Logitech Options: it works with some modern hardware but not all of them.
Logi Options+: (Logitech, are kidding us?) it works for the rest.

In all of those programs, the configuration is not to the hardware but to the software.

- In the case of setpoint, the configuration is in the settings.
- In the case of Logitech Options and Logi options+ (it is not the same program), the configuration is in the upper right corner (the wheel).